# ASP.NET Are ListViews redundant? Is there an alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

the current solution I am working on contains alot of list views, Are these really old controls that no body uses any more? Is there a better alternative?

Please give feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Erm, I think you've got your answer, listview = good :-) Nice article about the different controls: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Repeater-DataList-ListView-GridView.aspx

Comment: Why are you so concerned about them being old? If they do the job you're asking them to do, and have no issues, surely its popularity is a moot point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView is the best control available for data binding. You can write custom templates with complete control over its output, it supports sorting, paging, editing inline... do you need more?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't vote this down but...Move to ASP.net MVC? http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: I would love to!!!! my last position embraced MVC, but this place does not!! I am fully aware of the awsomeness of MVC

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET ListView controls just came out with .NET 3.5 around 2008.  They aren't that old and are useful for displaying certain kinds of data.

HTML ListBoxes on the other hand are kind of antiquated and visually unappealing.  I'm only mentioning this as I was confused by your comment about ListViews being old, and wonder if you're talking about the HTML control instead.  If so, you'd be better off looking at some other controls such as drop-down lists or some modern ajax-enabled controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Repeater control.

Comment: ListView is newer than the repeater control?